# microsoft ajax client side library document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

microsoft ajax client side library has different functions that mimic the server side Page Life Cycle and if (!Page.IsPostBack) conditions. I'm not sure which client side function correspond to the equivalent server side method.
In which order these client side functions are called? Which are called upon post backs and which are not?

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            //your start up code
        }
Sys.onReady(function() {
            //your start up code
        });
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
            //your start up code
        });
Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
            //your start up code
        });
```

when should I use one or the other?
which one is equivalent to Jquery $(document).ready() ?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Detect%20DOM%20Ready.ashx vs http://api.jquery.com/ready it's all in the documentation. the other two methods can be found there too.

Comment: thank you for the link, which I had already, but doesn't answer my question

Comment: How does it not answer... `$(document).ready` waits for the dom to be ready. `Sys.onReady` waits for the dom to be ready. Obviously they're both waiting for the dom to be ready. `pageLoad` is just a function and does nothing unless you attach it to something.

Comment: please view this other link, it will give you more information on the topic: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: You're still proving my point though. Everything you need to know about this information is in the documentation. Read it! I can answer this completely by simply going to the documentation page for each of those different scenarios and quoting descriptions.

Comment: I searched extensively but I didn't find a comprehensive documentation. where do I find it?

Comment: `add_load`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829(v=vs.100).aspx `add_init`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397532(v=vs.100).aspx the link you provided explains `pageLoad` pretty well in comparison to $(fn). Basically, add_init happens, then objects are loaded, then add_load happens. After that, pageLoad happens. document.ready is completely different from all of those because all it does is run when the browser's dom is ready, and never again, which is essentially the same thing that `Sys.onReady` does. http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Detect%20DOM%20Ready.ashx

Comment: Of course, i'm not an asp programmer, all of this is infor is coming directly from documentation using the searchbox in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the previous answers and comments I made some tests and I share here the an aspx page code that helps to understand the different choices you have to detect the Document Ready and the order they are called:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = '';
        //Ajax client side library offers two approaches to detect DOM ready, 
        //each one has two functions in order to detect an ajax callback call (equivalent to the serverside pageLoad Page.IsPostBack cycle)

        //DETECT DOM READY USING Sys.Application Events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384075(v=vs.100).aspx

        //1) equivalent serverside PageLoad WITH if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //Sys.Application.init Event, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397532(v=vs.100).aspx
        //Raised after all scripts have been loaded but before objects are created.
        Sys.Application.add_init(function () { //you can add as many as you like on the page
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp1').innerHTML = 'Sys.Application.init: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += '- Sys.Application.add_init -';
        });

        //2) equivalent to serverside PageLoad WITHOUT if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //Sys.Application.load Event, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829(v=vs.100).aspx
        //Raised after all scripts have been loaded and the objects in the application have been created and initialized.
        //The load event occurs immediately before the pageLoad event.
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp2').innerHTML = 'Sys.Application.add_load: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += ' - Sys.Application.add_load - ';
        });


        //DETECT DOM READY http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Detect%20DOM%20Ready.ashx

        //1) equivalent serverside PageLoad WITH if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        Sys.onReady(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp3').innerHTML = 'Sys.onReady: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += ' - Sys.onReady - ';
        });

        //2) equivalent to serverside PageLoad WITHOUT if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        function pageLoad(sender, args) { //it's a single global name. You can have only one per page
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp4').innerHTML = 'pageLoad: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += ' - pageLoad - ';
        }

        //JQUERY DOM READY
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp5').innerHTML = '$(document).ready: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += ' - $(document).ready - ';
        });
        $.fn.ready(function() {
            var d = new Date();
            $get('sp6').innerHTML = '$.fn.ready: ' + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
            test += ' - $.fn.ready - ';
        });

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $get('test').innerHTML = 'the functions where called in this order: ' + test;
        }, 1000);
    </script>
    <h2>Sys.Application</h2>
    <span id="sp1"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="sp2"></span>
    <h2>Dom Ready</h2>
    <span id="sp3"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="sp4"></span>
    <h2>JQuery</h2>
    <span id="sp5"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="sp6"></span>
    <span id="sp7"></span>
    <span id="sp8"></span>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="CallBack event" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<br />
<br />
<span id="test"></span>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            //your start up code

        }
```

**this function is to handle the load event of the Application object**

```
Sys.onReady(function() {
            //your start up code
        });
```

**this function is like document.ready in JQuery**

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
            //your start up code
        });

Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
            //your start up code
        });
```

**functions named add_eventname, example add_load and add_init, are to add for events raised by the Application and PageRequestManager classes.
add_load and function pageLoad(sender, args) are confusing but it's simple, pageload will be called after all add_load, example if you declare add_load{alert('add_load') and pageload{alert('pageload')} the first alert will be add_load then the other alert pageload.**
Hope that's clear.
Thanks

Comment: thank you, but I still do not understand what's the difference between Sys.Application.add_load and Sys.Application.add_init

Comment: take a look on asp.net page lifecycle